# Storing a list of 1 million key value pairs in python

Tags: python, redis, lookup, key-value

I need to store a list of 1 million key-value pairs in python. The key would be a string/integer while the value would be a list of float values. For example:

```
{"key":36520193,"value":[[36520193,16.946938],[26384600,14.44005],[27261307,12.467529],[16456022,11.316026],[26045102,8.891106],[148432817,8.043456],[36670593,7.111857],[43959215,7.0957513],[50403486,6.95],[18248919,6.8106747],[27563337,6.629243],[18913178,6.573106],[42229958,5.3193846],[17075840,5.266625],[17466726,5.2223654],[47792759,4.9141016],[83647115,4.6122775],[56806472,4.568034],[16752451,4.39949],[69586805,4.3642135],[23207742,3.9822476],[33517555,3.95],[30016733,3.8994896],[38392637,3.8642135],[16165792,3.6820507],[14895431,3.5713203],[48865906,3.45],[20878230,3.45],[17651847,3.3642135],[24484188,3.1820507],[74869104,3.1820507],[15176334,3.1571069],[50255841,3.1571069],[103712319,3.1571069],[20706319,2.9571068],[33542647,2.95],[17636133,2.95],[66690914,2.95],[19812372,2.95],[21178962,2.95],[37705610,2.8642135],[20812260,2.8642135],[25887809,2.8642135],[18815472,2.8642135],[17405810,2.8642135],[46598192,2.8642135],[20592734,2.6642137],[44971871,2.5],[27610701,2.45],[92788698,2.45],[52164826,2.45],[17425930,2.2],[60194002,2.1642137],[122136476,2.0660255],[205325522,2.0],[117521212,1.9820508],[33953887,1.9820508],[22704346,1.9571068],[26176058,1.9071068],[39512661,1.9071068],[43141485,1.8660254],[16401281,1.7],[31495921,1.7],[14599628,1.7],[74596964,1.5],[55821372,1.5],[109073560,1.4142135],[91897348,1.4142135],[25756071,1.25],[25683960,1.25],[17303288,1.25],[42065448,1.25],[72148532,1.2],[19192100,1.2],[85941613,1.2],[77325396,1.2],[18266218,1.2],[114005403,1.2],[16346823,1.2],[43441850,1.2],[60660643,1.2],[41463847,1.2],[33804454,1.2],[20757729,1.2],[18271440,1.2],[51507708,1.2],[104856807,1.2],[24485743,1.2],[16075381,1.2],[68991517,1.2],[96193545,1.2],[63675003,1.2],[70735999,1.2],[25708416,1.2],[80593161,1.2],[42982108,1.2],[120368215,1.2],[24379982,1.2],[14235673,1.2],[20172395,1.2],[161441314,1.2],[37996201,1.2],[35638883,1.2],[46164502,1.2],[74047763,1.2],[19681494,1.2],[95938476,1.2],[20443787,1.2],[87258609,1.2],[34784832,1.2],[30346151,1.2],[40885516,1.2],[197129344,1.2],[14266331,1.2],[15112466,1.2],[26867986,1.2],[82726479,1.2],[23825810,1.2],[14662121,1.2],[32707312,1.2],[17477917,1.2],[123462351,1.2],[5745462,1.2],[16544178,1.2],[23284384,1.2],[45526985,1.2],[23109303,1.2],[26046257,1.2],[53654203,1.2],[133026438,1.2],[25139051,1.2],[65077694,1.2],[17469289,1.2],[15130494,1.2],[148525895,1.2],[15176360,1.2],[44853617,1.2],[9115332,1.2],[16878570,1.2],[132421452,1.2],[6273762,1.2],[124360757,1.2],[21643452,1.2],[9890492,1.2],[16305494,1.2],[18484474,1.2],[22643607,1.2],[60753586,1.2],[9200012,1.2],[30042254,1.2],[8374622,1.2],[15894834,1.2],[18438022,1.2],[78038442,1.2],[22097386,1.2],[21018755,1.2],[20845703,1.2],[164462136,1.2],[19649167,1.2],[24746288,1.2],[27690898,1.2],[42822760,1.2],[160935289,1.2],[178814456,1.2],[53574205,1.2],[41473578,1.2],[82176632,1.2],[82918057,1.2],[102257360,1.2],[17504315,1.2],[18363508,1.2],[50735431,1.2],[80647070,1.2],[40879040,1.2],[17790497,1.2],[191364080,1.2],[14429823,1.2],[22078893,1.2],[121338184,1.2],[113341318,1.2],[48900101,1.2],[38547066,1.2],[20484157,1.2],[16228699,1.2],[21179292,1.2],[15317594,1.2],[55777010,1.2],[15318882,1.2],[182109160,1.2],[45238537,1.2],[19701986,1.2],[32484918,1.2],[18244358,1.2],[18479513,1.2],[19081775,1.2],[21117305,1.2],[19325724,1.2],[136844568,1.2],[32398651,1.2],[20482993,1.2],[14063937,1.2],[91324381,1.2],[20528275,1.2],[14803917,1.2],[16208245,1.2],[17419051,1.2],[31187903,1.2],[54043787,1.2],[167737676,1.2],[24431712,1.2],[24707301,1.2],[24420092,1.2],[15469536,1.2],[26322385,1.2],[77330594,1.2],[82925252,1.2],[28185335,1.0],[24510384,1.0],[24407244,1.0],[41229669,1.0],[16305330,1.0],[26246555,1.0],[28183026,1.0],[49880016,1.0],[104621640,1.0],[36880083,1.0],[19705747,1.0],[22830942,1.0],[21440766,1.0],[54639609,1.0],[49077908,1.0],[29588859,1.0],[23523447,1.0],[20803216,1.0],[20221159,1.0],[1416611,1.0],[3744541,1.0],[21271656,1.0],[68956490,1.0],[96851347,1.0],[39479083,1.0],[27778893,1.0],[18785448,1.0],[39010580,1.0],[65796371,1.0],[124631720,1.0],[27039286,1.0],[18208354,1.0],[51080209,1.0],[37388787,1.0],[18462037,1.0],[31335156,1.0],[21346320,1.0],[23911410,1.0],[73134924,1.0],[807095,1.0],[44465330,1.0],[16732482,1.0],[37344334,1.0],[734753,1.0],[23006794,1.0],[33549858,1.0],[102693093,1.0],[51219631,1.0],[20695699,1.0],[4081171,1.0],[27268078,1.0],[80116664,1.0],[32959253,1.0],[85772748,1.0],[27109019,1.0],[28706024,1.0],[59701568,1.0],[23559586,1.0],[15693493,1.0],[56908710,1.0],[6541402,1.0],[15855538,1.0],[126169000,1.0],[24044209,1.0],[80700514,1.0],[21500333,1.0],[18431316,1.0],[44496963,1.0],[68475722,1.0],[15202472,1.0],[19329393,1.0],[39706174,1.0],[22464533,1.0],[81945172,1.0],[22101236,1.0],[19140282,1.0],[31206614,1.0],[15429857,1.0],[27711339,1.0],[14939981,1.0],[62591681,1.0],[52551600,1.0],[40359919,1.0],[27828234,1.0],[21414413,1.0],[156132825,1.0],[21586867,1.0],[23456995,1.0],[25434201,1.0],[30107143,1.0],[34441838,1.0],[37908934,1.0],[47010618,1.0],[139903189,1.0],[17833574,1.0],[758608,1.0],[15823236,1.0],[37006875,1.0],[10302152,1.0],[40416155,1.0],[21813730,1.0],[18785600,1.0],[30715906,1.0],[428333,1.0],[22059385,1.0],[15155074,1.0],[11061902,1.0],[1177521,1.0],[20449160,1.0],[197117628,1.0],[42423692,1.0],[24963961,1.0],[19637934,1.0],[35960001,1.0],[43269420,1.0],[43283406,1.0],[20269113,1.0],[59409413,1.0],[25548759,1.0],[23779324,1.0],[21449197,1.0],[14327149,1.0],[15429316,1.0],[16159485,1.0],[18785846,1.0],[67651295,1.0],[28389815,1.0],[19780922,1.0],[23841181,1.0],[78391198,1.0],[60765383,1.0],[37689397,1.0],[6447142,1.0],[31332871,1.0],[30364057,1.0],[14120151,1.0],[16303064,1.0],[23023236,1.0],[103610974,1.0],[108382988,1.0],[19791811,1.0],[17121755,1.0],[46346811,1.0],[45618045,1.0],[25587721,1.0],[25362775,1.0],[20710218,1.0],[20223138,1.0],[21035409,1.0],[101894425,1.0],[38314814,1.0],[24582667,1.0],[21181713,1.0],[15901190,1.0],[18197299,1.0],[38802447,1.0],[19668592,1.0],[14515734,1.0],[16870853,1.0],[16488614,1.0],[95955871,1.0],[14780915,1.0],[21188490,1.0],[24243022,1.0],[27150723,1.0],[29425265,1.0],[36370563,1.0],[36528126,1.0],[43789332,1.0],[82773533,1.0],[19726043,1.0],[20888549,1.0],[30271564,1.0],[14874125,1.0],[121436823,1.0],[56405314,1.0],[46954727,1.0],[25675498,1.0],[12803352,1.0],[23888081,1.0],[18498684,1.0],[38536306,1.0],[22851295,1.0],[20140595,1.0],[22311506,1.0],[31121729,1.0],[53717630,1.0],[100101137,1.0],[24753205,1.0],[24523660,1.0],[19544133,1.0],[20823773,1.0],[22677790,1.0],[15227791,1.0],[57525419,1.0],[28562317,1.0],[9629222,1.0],[24047612,1.0],[30508215,1.0],[59084417,1.0],[71088774,1.0],[142157505,1.0],[15284851,1.0],[17164788,1.0],[17885166,1.0],[18420140,1.0],[19695929,1.0],[20572844,1.0],[23479429,1.0],[26642006,1.0],[43469093,1.0],[50835878,1.0],[172049453,1.0],[20604508,1.0],[21681591,1.0],[20052907,1.0],[21271938,1.0],[17842661,1.0],[6365162,1.0],[18130749,1.0],[19249062,1.0],[24193336,1.0],[25913173,1.0],[28647246,1.0],[26072121,1.0],[14522546,1.0],[16409683,1.0],[18785475,1.0],[28969818,1.0],[52757166,1.0],[7120172,1.0],[112237392,1.0],[116779546,1.0],[57107167,1.0],[26347170,1.0],[26565946,1.0],[44409004,1.0],[21105244,1.0],[14230524,1.0],[44711134,1.0],[101753075,1.0],[783214,1.0],[22885110,1.0],[39367703,1.0],[23042739,1.0],[682903,1.0],[38082423,1.0],[16194263,1.0],[2425151,1.0],[52544275,1.0],[21380763,1.0],[18948541,1.0],[34954261,1.0],[34848331,1.0],[29245563,1.0],[19499974,1.0],[16089776,1.0],[77040291,1.0],[18197476,1.0],[1704551,1.0],[15002838,1.0],[17428652,1.0],[20702626,1.0],[29049111,1.0],[34004383,1.0],[34900333,1.0],[48156959,1.0],[50906836,1.0],[15742480,1.0],[41073372,1.0],[37338814,1.0],[1344951,1.0],[8320242,1.0],[14719153,1.0],[20822636,1.0],[168841922,1.0],[19877186,1.0],[14681605,1.0],[15033883,1.0],[23121582,1.0],[23670204,1.0],[41466869,1.0],[18753325,1.0],[21358050,1.0],[78132538,1.0],[132386271,1.0],[86194654,1.0],[17225211,1.0],[107179714,1.0],[18785430,1.0],[19408059,1.0],[19671129,1.0],[24347716,1.0],[24444592,1.0],[25873045,1.0],[7871252,1.0],[14138300,1.0],[16873300,1.0],[14546496,1.0],[165964253,1.0],[15529287,1.0],[95956928,1.0],[19404587,1.0],[21506437,1.0],[22832029,1.0],[19542638,1.0],[30827536,1.0],[5748622,1.0],[22757990,1.0],[41259253,1.0],[23738945,1.0],[19030602,1.0],[21410102,1.0],[28206360,1.0],[136411179,1.0],[17499805,1.0],[26107245,1.0],[127311408,1.0],[77023233,1.0],[20448733,1.0],[20683840,1.0],[22482597,1.0],[15485441,1.0],[28220280,1.0],[55351351,1.0],[70942325,1.0],[9763482,1.0],[15732001,1.0],[27750488,1.0],[18286352,1.0],[122216533,1.0],[19562228,1.0],[5380672,1.0],[22293700,1.0],[59974874,1.0],[44455025,1.0],[90420314,1.0],[22657153,1.0],[16660662,1.0],[14583400,1.0],[16689545,1.0],[94242867,1.0],[44527648,1.0],[40366319,1.0],[33616007,1.0],[23438958,1.0],[15317676,1.0],[14075928,1.0],[1978331,1.0],[33347901,1.0],[16570090,1.0],[32347966,1.0],[26671992,1.0],[101907019,1.0],[24986014,1.0],[23235056,1.0],[40001164,1.0],[21891032,1.0],[18139329,1.0],[9648652,1.0],[16105942,1.0],[3004231,1.0],[20762929,1.0],[28061932,1.0],[39513172,1.0],[15012305,1.0],[18349404,1.0],[22196210,1.0],[110509537,1.0],[20318494,1.0],[21816984,1.0],[22456686,1.0],[62290422,1.0],[93472506,0.8660254],[52305889,0.70710677],[67337055,0.70710677],[122768292,0.5],[35060854,0.5],[43289205,0.5],[87271142,0.5],[28096898,0.5],[79297090,0.5],[24016107,0.5],[48736472,0.5],[109982897,0.5],[98367357,0.5],[21816847,0.5],[73129588,0.5],[23807734,0.5],[76724998,0.5],[63153228,0.5],[21628966,0.5],[14465428,0.5],[42609851,0.5],[30213342,0.5],[17021966,0.5],[96616361,0.5],[97546740,0.5],[67613930,0.5],[21234391,0.5],[87245558,0.5],[36841912,0.5]]}
```

I would be performing lookups on this data structure. What would be the most appropriate data structure to achieve my purpose? I have heard recommendations about [Redis](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis). Would it be worth looking into it rather than the traditional python data structure? If not, please suggest other mechanisms.

**Edit**

The 'value' field is a list of lists. Most cases, the list may be upto 1000 lists consisting of a size-2 list.

Comment: 1M pairs is a decent amount, as long as your posting list (ie. the floats) is reasonably small. Have you tried to compute how much memory you would require to store it in memory as a regular dict?

Comment: "performing lookups" is vague. In what context? Have you **tried** just using a `dict`? What requirements do you have that aren't satisfied? If you haven't tried, what's preventing you from trying?

Comment: @savinos No, I haven't really calculated but the used memory does increase exponentially. Would Redis be the best solution? I want an efficient lookup data structure.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel A lookup would be to check if the key exists in the dictionary. I did try using a dictionary *but* the process takes up huge amount of memory and hangs my machine. Is it normal to have 1M keys in a normal python dict?

Comment: Why not just lose the 'key' and 'value' and store the entry as {36520193: [[36520193.....} in a standard dictionary?

Comment: @Bogdan tried it but memory increases exponentially and freezes my machine. Hence, the question.

Comment: I see no problem with a dict with 1M keys.

Comment: @Bogdan Ok, let me try. I am storing other things in memory apart from the dictionary too. Let me check, thanks.

Comment: @gnibbler I am just worried about the size of the 'value' field. In some cases the value field may contain a list of 1000 2-value lists.

Comment: @mcenley, well those values are a lot larger than the examples you mentioned in your question :)

Comment: So you have 1000000 keys, and some of the values contain 2000 integers?

Comment: @gnibbler Absolutely! I couldn't post all of those for obvious reasons and my bad I didn't mention it in the first place. I am adding an edit. Now, considering these constraints does using a python dict still sound good?

Comment: maybe you need to run your code on the amazon cloud :) If you shove 64GB in a PC, it might be enough, but any processing on the data set is going to be quite slow. Lookups would still be fast though :)

Comment: @gnibbler Ah! I do have 1 Million keys but each of these keys point to a 1000 value list. Each value in this 1000 value list contains another 2-value list. I am not sure if it in principle equates to 2000 integers in terms of memory but in terms of simple math ... yes! :-)

Comment: @gnibbler So dictionary may not be a good idea after all. :-( Would Redis work?

Comment: @mcenley, redis will need enough RAM to store the whole data set too, otherwise you are still hitting the disk

Comment: _"A lookup would be to check if the key exists in the dictionary."_ You don't have to store the values in memory in that case.

Comment: @JanneKarila Ah! I must add that if the key exists, I need to retrieve the value too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redis would be appropriate if...

- You want to share the queue between multiple processes or instances of your app.
- You want the data to be persistent, so if your app goes down it can pick up where it left off.
- You want a super fast, easy solution.
- Memory usage is a concern.

I'm not sure on the last one, but I'm guessing using `dict` or some other collection type in Python is likely to have a higher memory footprint than storing all your key/values in a single Redis hash.

#### update

I tested the memory usage by storing the example array 1 million times both in memory and in redis. Storing all the values in a Redis hash requires serializing the array. I chose json serialization, but this could have easily been a more efficient binary format, which redis supports.

- 1 million copies of the array provided in a Ruby `Hash` (should be comparable to Python's `dict`) indexed using an integer key similar to the one shown. Memory usage increased by ~350mb (similar to the python results by @gnibbler).
- 1 million copies of the array, serialized to a JSON string in a redis hash indexed using the same numbers. Memory usage increased by ~250mb.

Both were very fast, with the Redis being slightly faster when I measured 10,000 random lookups vs random lookups against the native collection. I know it's not Python, but this should be at least illustrative.

Also, to answer the OPs other concern, Redis has no trouble handing very large string values. It's max string size is currently [512mb](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)

Comment: Thanks, I am just worried about the size of the 'value' field. In some cases the value field may contain a list of 1000 2-value lists.

Comment: @mcenley For a compact representation of an array of floats, look into [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), or into [NumPy](http://numpy.scipy.org/) if you need to do some heavy computations on the array.

Comment: @JanneKarila Just in case, I don't think the 'value' field is an array  of floats.

Comment: Carl, Thanks. I presume you are telling me that a Python dictionary is as good as an array. Did you get a lower memory size due to the same key-value pair being added multiple times? Apologies, but I'm just thinking loud here.

Comment: @mcenley I was storing Ruby `Array`s within a Ruby `Hash`, which should be similar to a Python `dict` containing `tuple`s with your values. The array value stored didn't vary, but the key did. I used the same keys and values for redis. I don't think the repeating values saved any memory. Redis wouldn't have compressed the 1mil key hash like it does with small hashes.

Comment: @CarlZulauf So, what would be your final recommendation? Python dict, NumPy array or Redis?

Comment: @mcenley I don't know what your application will be doing exactly, but for all but the simplest app I'd go with Redis. Fast, reliable, robust, memory efficient, and persistent... and almost as easy as just using `dict`.

Answer (score 4):

Really shouldn't be a problem

```
>>> d=dict((str(n), range(20)) for n in range(1000000))
```

took ~350MB to create. Your keys/values may be much larger of course

Comment: my value 'field' may be as long as a list of 1000 2-float value lists.
[[36520193,16.946938], ..... 1000 such lists]

Comment: If memory is more of an issue than acces time you could use numpy objects to store the arrays in files. You could just use numpy.save / numpy.load on the arrays which for a 1000*2 should be very fast and use the dictionary keys as the file names.

Comment: You may even find a middle ground where you keep like the last x accesed list in memory and the rest in files.

Comment: @Bogdan The whole point of using a dictionary was to avoid a disk read and a web api call. While the solution is plausible, I am looking for something better if exists.

Comment: Well you would need to hold up 1.000.000 * 1.000 * 2 * 4 bytes even in a flatten list with all your elements. That's 8gb right there, with some form of lookup that has to increase. I don't really know any good options for that. I'll still favourite this tread because I'm curious what your solution will be.

Comment: @mcenley "my value 'field' may be as long as a list of 1000 2-float value lists" is the most important information indeed

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks! I am curious too. I am out to try Redis.

Comment: @savinos Sorry for missing that earlier mate.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at storage in NumPy and also in redis.

First, NumPy:

```
>>> import numpy as NP
>>> K = NP.random.randint(1000, 9999, 1e6)
>>> V = 5 * NP.random.rand(2e6).reshape(-1, 2)

>>> kv = K.nbytes + V.nbytes
>>> '{:15,d}'.format(kv)
>>> '      2,400,000'     # 2.4 MB
```

Now redis:

I represented the values as *strings*, which should be very efficient in redis.

```
>>> from redis import Redis   # using the python client for redis

>>> # w/ a server already running:
>>> r0 = Redis(db=0)

>>> for i in range(K.shape[0]) :
        v = ' '.join(NP.array(V[i], dtype=str).tolist())
        r0.set(K[i], v)

>>> # save db to disk asynchronously, then shut down the server
>>> r0.shutdown()
```

The redis database (.rdb file) is **2.9 MB**

Of course, this is not an "apples-to-apples" comparison because i chose what i believed to be the most natural model to represent the OP's data in each library--i.e., **redis** (*strings*) than for **NumPy** (2-element NumPy *array*).

Comment: So, what do you recommend? Python dict, NumPy or Redis?

Comment: well, i often use both for the same project--redis provides *durable persistence* across sessions (it's possible to persist a pure NumPy array by serializing it, but the file, '*.npy' is massive; and NumPy provides excellent compact structures and an excellent API for computation. You can obviously do that, or chose one, in which case the choice probably distills to how much durability you need (if hi, go w/ redis).